# Change default color of Firefox when opening links in a new tab

Tags: firefox, css, styles

I'm using Stylish addon for Firefox with a default dark `css`. I also have changed the default Window colors in Windows registry. This has changed the `about:blank` page's color to a dark one. But when I open a link on a new tab, before the page loads, Firefox is showing a blank page with **white** background. I wonder how can I change this white color to a different one.

Comment: Related: *[How to change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other color and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-to-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-color-and-f/638257#638257)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder named "Chrome" in this location: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile]\chrome`

and created an empty `userChrome.css` file with this line:

`browser { background-color: #373739 !important; }`

It worked fine for me.