# Change default color of Chrome when opening links in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, css, styles

I have a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/447528/change-default-color-of-firefox-when-opening-links-in-a-new-tab) about firefox in SU.

I'm using Stylish extension and I have changed the style of many websites to dark. When I open a link on a new tab, before the page loads, Chrome is showing a blank page with white background. How can I change this white color to a different one. Is there a CSS selector for it? Does chrome support something like `userChrome.css` file in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my box (ubuntu 12+) custom css is possible:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

As for now, it's not (yet) possible for chrome://newtab/ , see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html for more information.

creds @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362698/is-it-possible-to-change-the-google-chrome-default-document-area-ui-through-exte .

related : [Changing the background image of Chrome’s NTP](https://superuser.com/questions/304494/background-image-in-google-chrome) (changing the background by altering a dll-file).

If you're compiling your own chrom[e|ium], see: http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/new-tab-page .

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't have to do so much work. I opened this file: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` and wrote this line: `body { background: #373739 }` Worked just fine. The wonderful thing is that I don't have to restart Chrome for this settings to apply. It will work as soon as I hit save.