# How can I change the color of active tab? (Linux)

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome. Is there any possibility to change the color of active tab in chrome without changing the theme?

I use GTK+ theme and I want to keep the consistency. Now active and inactive tabs are the same color this is hard to differentiate them.

This is how tabs in Chrome look
[image]

This is how how tabs in Firefox look, much easier to tell which one is active
[image]

Comment: Likely this can be done through cusatom.css. See https://superuser.com/questions/459901/change-default-color-of-chrome-when-opening-links-in-a-new-tab

Comment: You mean in the tab bar itself, the actual tab, not a new tab's background? Chromium already seems to do this (a little), darker grey for inactive, light grey when hovering over, and even lighter grey when active. Firefox had great extensions/add-ons for this, but Chrome's web store seems to only have "change new tab background" extensions... maybe your searching there will be more fruitful

Comment: @Xen2050 yes, tab itself.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ubuntu Black Magic Theme - U.F.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ubuntu-black-magic-theme/nnckfbibnhikbljjnipfknnmjpafdbla?hl=en-US) seems to have a higher contrast between active (white) & inactive (dark grey) tabs.

Here's the screenshot from it's page, though inactive tabs look darker on Debian xfce, looks like a one-click install & undo so definitely worth a try at least:

[image]

How dark/light a theme makes the tab bar doesn't seem to be advertised well, so browsing & randomly trying a few might bring some luck.

Comment: I prefer not to change the chrome theme to keep the UI consistency with GTK.

Comment: Themes only seem to change the window bar & border colours for me, which seems like most of your goal, but maybe searching you'll find a theme that matches your gtk theme